# Pybind11 - Bound class method returns new class instance, rather than editing in-place

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, pybind11

I am unable to return the input of a class method (input: specific instances of a seperate class) to Python. The binding compiles and I can use the resulting module in Python. The class method should however return the same instances as it admits (after some processing).

The `Obstacle` class is used as the input. The `ObstacleProcess` class has a method (Python: `__call__` / C++: `operator_py`) which processes the input (instances of `Obstacle`). The following Python code shows that different instances of `Obstacle` is returned:

```py
import example

obstacle_1 = example.Obstacle()
obstacle_2 = example.Obstacle()

obstacles = [obstacle_1, obstacle_2]
print(obstacles)

params = example.Params()
obstacle_process = example.ObstacleProcess(params)
obstacles = obstacle_process(obstacles)
print(obstacles)
```

The first print returns: `[<example.Obstacle object at 0x7fb65271e1b0>, <example.Obstacle at 0x7fb652735070>]`, whilst the second print retuns: `[<example.Obstacle at 0x7fb652734670>, <example.Obstacle object at 0x7fb652735230>]`.

This is not the desired output as `obstacle_1` initially lives at `0x7fb65271e1b0`, and after the `operator()`/`__call__` call  it lives at `0x7fb652734670`. I want `obstacle_1` to keep its initial address of `0x7fb65271e1b0`, even after the other class (`ObstacleProcess`) has processed `obstacle_1`.

The following code shows the source code is bound with pybind11:

```cpp
// pybind11 binding
py::class_<Obstacle, std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>(m, "Obstacle")
    .def(py::init<>());

py::class_<ObstacleProcess>(m, "ObstacleProcess")
    .def(py::init<
        const Params&>()
    )
    .def("__call__", &ObstacleProcess::operator_py<Params>, py::return_value_policy::reference);
```

The next block shows how `operator_py` is implemented in the source code:

```cpp
template <Params>
std::vector<Obstacle>& operator_py(
    std::vector<Obstacle>& obstacles,
    const Params &parameters
)
{

    ...

    return obstacles
}
```

I have tried with and without `std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>`. The current implementation gives the same result as not using `shared_ptr` at all, thus there is something wrong with how I have implemented `shared_ptr`. I have tried to use `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Obstacle>>);`, but my implementation of this did not change the result.

I have not tried to use the `pybind11 — smart_holder branch`, maybe this branch has to be used for this case?

Comment: You're returning `std::vector<Obstacle>` by value in `operator_py`...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @DanMašek! I however, unfortunately only made this mistake when typing down the MWE in my question. Do you see anything else that is wrong?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but would a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>` make any difference?

Comment: You are thinking in operator_py() or in py::class_<Obstacle, std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>(m, "Obstacle")?

Comment: `operator_py`. Because right now, the vector holds the Obstacles by value as well, which I'd expect to involve a copy when populating it.

Comment: I am actually using `std::vector<Obstacle, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Obstacle>>` (and not `std::vector<Obstacle>`) , so I had to do: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>> &obstacles`. This type is a bit confusing, so I don't know how to get "back" the `Obstacle` from this type such that I can process it.

Comment: IMHO the allocator shouldn't make any difference in how you access the elements. So `obstacles[i]`/`at`/iteration would give you individual shared pointers, which you can dereference (`*obstacles[i]`) to get the `Obstacle` instance they hold. However, given that now you have a vector of smart pointers, as opposed to vector of `Obstacle`s, I'd say there's no benefit of using `aligned_allocator` at all (since the smart pointers don't really need a non-standard alignment, and the extra level of indirection that introduce means you no longer have a flat array of `Obstacle`s in memory)..

Comment: Assuming that you had that allocator there for a good reason (i guess performance), a wholly different approach might be appropriate, although to judge that properly, I think I'd have to see a lot more context than what is currently available in your question.

Comment: I have gotten the code to compile and run in Python, but I am getting a segmentation fault when using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>> &obstacles`. I am not quite sure what to use as input from the Python side with this new input type...

Comment: I'll try to run without the allocator to see if i can avoid the seg fault

Comment: Tested without allocator, seg fault still present. I imagine it has to do with my input from Python. Not sure how to create  `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>` from the Python side. I am passing my input to `__call__` in the same manner as I did when the input was of type `std::vector<Obstacle>`, this seems wrong.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'll make one and share it here @n.m.willseey'allonReddit! Just to have asked: Do you immediately see anything wrong with the dereferencing in the last implementation of `operator_py()`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, primarily because I don't see anything I can check. I would like to look at something *testable*. A bunch of ellipses and undefined identifiers ain't it.

Comment: Offcourse! MWE on the way :-)

Comment: So I just completed the MWE, and it worked like expected, output:
`[<exampleModule.Obstacle object at 0x7fe93e99b4b0>, <exampleModule.Obstacle object at 0x7fe93e99b470>]
[<exampleModule.Obstacle object at 0x7fe93e99b4b0>, <exampleModule.Obstacle object at 0x7fe93e99b470>]`. Hence the mistake is inside the "processing" body of operator_py(). I'll update when I figure out the mistake with my processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments from @DanMašek and @n.m.willseey'allonReddit it was unveiled that making these changes to `operator_py()` fixes the issue in the question:

```cpp
template <class Params>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>>& operator_py(
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obstacle>> &obstacles,
    const Params &params
    )
    {
    for (auto& obstacle : obstacles)
        {
             obstacle->someObstacleClassMethod()
             someObstacleProcessMethod(obstacles, params)
        }   
    return obstacles;
    }
```

With this implemented the desired output was obtained:

```py
import example

obstacle_1 = example.Obstacle()
obstacle_2 = example.Obstacle()

obstacles = [obstacle_1, obstacle_2]
print(obstacles)

params = example.Params()
obstacle_process = example.ObstacleProcess(params)
obstacles = obstacle_process(obstacles)
print(obstacles)

# output:
[<example.Obstacle object at 0x7f709bdc2430>, <example.Obstacle object at 0x7f709b12a830>]
[<example.Obstacle object at 0x7f709bdc2430>, <example.Obstacle object at 0x7f709b12a830>]
```

Comment: Glad it helped. I bet you could also get rid of that intermediate vector and marge both loops together.

Comment: Yeah, probably! But I'd have to rewrite some stuff as I have some methods which admits `obstacles` and a lot of other stuff which only uses `obstacle` inside the last loop.

Comment: Correct again @DanMašek! Removed the unnecessary loop as `obstacles` and `obstacle` should be used directly as shown in the answer. Now the answer is completed (Y).